# Doctrine ODM(mongoDB) query command

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, doctrine-odm

I've a problem with executing Doctrine command:

```
php bin/console doctrine:mongodb:query "db.store.find({})"
```

and the result is:

```
Not enough arguments (missing: "query").
```

can anyone explain what is the correct way of providing a query to the command? In the documentation I can't find any examples.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've managed to make it work.

For anyone interested, the correct format is:

```
php bin/console doctrine:mongodb:query App\\Document\\Store\\Store '{"name": "Store A"}'
```

where the first part is the name of a class, and the second one is a text query that can be decoded to a JSON.